# java json array parsing with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following json file

```
[{"key1":"value11", "key2":"value12"},{"key1":"value21", "key2":"value22"},...]
```

How can I get each json Object from that array using Jackson. One note here is that the json file is Big ~ 700MB. I want read JSON object one by one process and load data into database

```
 step 1: {"key1":"value11", "key2":"value12"}
 step 2: {"key1":"value21", "key2":"value22"}
 ...
```

so i need to load all that information into database. let say i have one table in database:

```
create table mytbl
(
  key1 varchar2(100),
  key2 varchar2(100)
)
```

so each key should go into his column.

Comment: If your JSON input is that big then you want to use the streaming API; it is doable, now you need to be more precise about what you really want. Reading an element is easy, what to do with it is the question.

Comment: i added some more explanation, maybe that will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to share how I get that, maybe someone will use ...

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonParser parser = mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonParser(new File(ConfigurationManager.jsonfile));

JsonToken token = parser.nextToken();

if (token == null) {
    System.out.println("no json file");
}

if (!JsonToken.START_ARRAY.equals(token)) {
    System.out.println("Expected an array");
}   

while (!JsonToken.END_ARRAY.equals(parser.nextToken())) {   
    System.out.println(parser.readValueAsTree().toString()));

    // parse json object here
}       

parser.close();
```